# MS Word Macro ... unable to insert PNG

Tags: vba, png, ms-word

**Has anyone had problems inserting a PNG file into a word document, using a VBA Macro?**

I have an MS Word document that contains a *very large* directory listing of image files, inside a table.  I've been asked to update the document by inserting the corresponding image in front of the name.

Now, if I enter the image manually (using `Insert|Image|From File`), I'm able to successfully place the PNG image ... so I decided to write a quick VBA Macro to insert the image for me.  The following is a sample of the code:

```
Dim myFile  As String
Selection.SelectCell
Selection.Copy
myFile = _
   Chr(34) & "C:\Documents and Settings\...\Project\Images\" _
   & Left(Selection.Text, Len(Selection.Text) - 2) & Chr(34)

Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
   FileName:=myFile, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
```

Outcomes:

- Whenever I execute the macro, I get the "*Unable to Convert*" error dialog, and no image is inserted.
- I even changed the code to invoke the `wdDialogInsertPicture` Dialog instead, and it worked just fine.

This is very confusing ... using a **manual** process, the insert works, but going with an **automated** solution, the insert *doesn't* work!

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Is it because a whole cell is selected at the time you're inserting the picture?

Comment: I ran the macro against the file, just to verify your question, and here's what I found: If I just place the cursor in front of the text and run the macro, the cell becomes selected and then is de-selected once the error dialog appears.  If I select the entire cell before running the macro, the cursor is automatically placed in front of the text once the error dialog appears.

Comment: Insert a breakpoint and tell us what the value of myFile is before you run the insert code. My bet is that the file path has not been properly set up. For instance, I don't think you should be inserting the Chr(34) before and after the file path. The path passed to AddPicture is not supposed to be surrounded by quotation marks or anything else, it's the straight up file path. It's allowed to contain spaces. I think you're getting confused with command line utilities.

Comment: @Alain - I removed the Chr(34) entries and had the same problem.  However, during the process of debugging the macro, my machine crashed.  After rebooting, I attempted to run the macro and IT WORKED.  I have NO explanation

Comment: Cheers then :p Office VBA occasionally gets into a similar state of nonsensically breaking or throwing errors that don't normally occur, and restarting my computer always solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the macro several times and it works ... it seems that I'm no longer able to re-create the error again.  So, I'm going to mark this under the "mysteries of Office VBA" column and leave it as is ... this is not a high-priority project, so there is no need for me to continue investigating.

Thanks to **Alain** and **Joel Spolsky** for their help.